# The type 'System.Drawing.Image' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use fo-dicom.

I'm following [their example on converting a .dcm image to .jpg](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom#render-image-to-jpeg).

```
var image = new DicomImage(@"test.dcm");
image.RenderImage().Save(@"test.jpg");
```

I'm getting the following error in the line that calls `Save()`:

```
The type 'System.Drawing.Image' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm asking how to add this reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Visual studio, right click on your project -> Add -> Reference. On the Framework tab, choose System.Drawing.

An easy way to figure out which assembly a class is in is to check out the MSDN docs. For example, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Some time I have a little error about something like assembly. I usally try Clean Solution then Rebuild my Project and It`s works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, go to the Solution Explorer and right-click on "References"-> "Add reference". This opens a Reference Manager box. Click on "Assemblies" and use the "Search Assemblies" to find system.drawing file. Put a checkbox against it and click OK. This will add the reference to the project.

[image]